# data-masking and retrieving data back

Tags: c#, data-masking

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FromTime,ToTime,CustomerID,UserID,Description,Type,CreatedTime")] Schedule schedule)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(schedule).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "ID", "Name", schedule.CustomerID);
    ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "ID", "Name", schedule.UserID);
    //return View(schedule);
    return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Schedules", action = "Index" });
}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ToTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The type of `FromTime` and `ToTime` is long and i want to display it as Time and then save it back as long.

If I have a type of long in the database and i need to display it as Time in Model View Controller ASP.Net then save it as a long again into the database. How can i do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. See duplicate to convert a long to a datetime.

Comment: @tereško please read the question before applying irrelevant tags.

Comment: @CodeCaster , you might notice that I **replaced** a tag. IT was tagged with "mvc", and I changed it to "asp.net-mvc", which was what OP intended to use. Since there is a possibility that OP was not talking about "time" as a data type but as some sort of time-picker widget.

Comment: Please how can i add an attachment so you can get my point maybe i didn't ask the question in a proper way.

Comment: Try using the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{youtformat}")]` on model property

Comment: @CoderofCode I tried the [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{youtformat}")] before but when i use it i am getting an error that says the input string was not in the correct format on the Index view.

Comment: I can tell you the workaround as create 2 separate properties one for display and one for database and use that respectively wherever you need. But there might be better way of doing it as i am unknown to the MVC.

Comment: @CoderofCode I tried creating two separate properties as you mentioned but the problem is after displaying i have to convert it back from a the formatted string back to string then back to long to save it in the database.

Comment: @CoderofCode But thanks anyways i appreciate your will to help. Regards